# Eliminar espacio entre el div superior e inferior

Tags: html, css

Quiero que los dos divs esten en la misma posicion, pero pegados entre ellos, lo que me hace el hueco, y no entiendo por qué lo hace ni cómo quitarlo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        header {
            height: 4em;
            width: 100%;
            border: 3px solid #ccc;
        }

        main {
            margin: 1px;
            height: 25em;
            width: 100%;
            border: 3px solid #ccc;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: flex-start
        }

        article {
            height: 23em;
            width: 22em;
            border: 3px solid black;
            margin-left: 5px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
           

        }

        .container-img {
            height: 15em;
            margin: 2px;
            width: 18em;
            border: 3px solid black;
            
        }

        .container-title {
            height: 5em;
            width: 18em;
            border: 3px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header></header>
    <main>
        <article>
            <div class="container-img"></div>
            <div class="container-title"></div>
        </article>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- En lugar de usar `flex-wrap` para mover el segundo `div` al renglón siguiente, puedes aplicar el uso de `flex-direction` con un valor de `column`
- Lo anterior nos ayudará a que los elementos queden apilados uno encima del otro
- Al contenedor padre le das un `padding` para separar a los 2 `div` de su borde
- Al segundo `div` le damos un ancho definido (*que igual cuando ya le coloques contenido real no será necesario*) y logramos el aspecto deseado

Código:

```html
    <style>
      article {
        border: 1px solid;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 25px;
        width: 400px;
      }
      
      .container-img,
      .container-title{
        border: 1px solid crimson;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .container-title {
        height: 100px;
      }
    </style>
    
    <article>
      <div class="container-img">1</div>
      <div class="container-title">2</div>
    </article>
```

**Referencia**

- [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)